# The package org is not accessible - Selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, automation-testing

I am trying write a selenium code using Java but there is an error package org is not accessible.

I have downloaded a firefox driver and given a path. Please let me know. It will be appreciated.

Please find the code below

```
package Selenium.webdriver.basictests;

    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    
    public class Firsttest {
    
        public static void main(String [] args) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C://Users//97477//.eclipse//geckodriver.exe");
            
            FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
    }
```

[SeleniumWebdriverErrors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2QZl.png)

Please the location of my project folder and let me know the next step because it still showing an error.

[Please check the location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUy22.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things:

instead of this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C://Users//97477//.eclipse//geckodriver.exe");
```

use this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",Path_of_Firefox_Driver"); // Setting system properties of FirefoxDriver
```

and

instead of this:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

use this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //Creating an object of FirefoxDriver
```

refer this image:

[image]

Comment: Please check the code . it still not worked for me

Comment: what do you mean? In the comment, I see you've pasted my code and said` it still worked for me` - did it work for you ?

Comment: Sorry I have edited . it hasn't worked for me.

Comment: what is the error do you see ?

Comment: Firefoxdriver cannot resolved to a type. Webdriver cannot resolve to a type. It will be highly appreciated if you help. thanks

Comment: okay declare `WebDriver driver` outside of the main method and then assign it when we are creating the object. `driver = new FirefoxDriver(); ` something like this.

Comment: Ok I have declared outside main. it gives syntax error on token driver 'Variable declarationtoId ' expected after token.      it highlight red on driver=....

Comment: @AmmadHassan: Refer the image that I have uploaded. I don't know that youtuber, I know that my solution should work.

Comment: Sure, Thanks. I will implement and update you. :)

Comment: Import these as well: `import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;`

Comment: what should I write instead of package com.stackoverflow.cruisepandey... ?

Comment: the package name where you've created this class, I think this is the one `package Selenium.webdriver.basictests;`

Comment: Please check the screenshot I have posted with a name  SeleniumWebdriverErrors

Comment: You can see below my code.

Comment: where are Selenium libraries ? have you downloaded it ?

Comment: I have only downloaded the gecko driver. Can you please refer me the link.

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/

Comment: download the Java one.

Comment: Sure, thanks , I have already downloaded. there are jar files in it. where to keep this folder. my eclipse is in C:\users\9772\eclipse

Comment: go to your project location and then create a lib folder, paster everything and make sure to add these jar to build path

Comment: Hi. I added the folder in the location. Also attached the screenshot. if you can check how to update it and see if the error is resolved.

Comment: You should not edit my answer, instead you should update your question if there's any relevant thing to update.